# gcc weird conversion warning (conversion to ‘A<B>::count_type {aka short unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have following C++11 code using templates:

```
struct Base{
    using count_type = unsigned short;
};

template<class T>
struct A : public Base{
    using count_type = A::count_type;
    // not works even if I comment this

    count_type add(T x){
        count_type sum = 5;
        sum += x.value(); 
        //sum += (count_type) x.value(); // not works even if I cast this, e.g.


        return sum;
    }
};

struct B{
    using count_type = A<B>::count_type;

    count_type value(){
        return 5; // not works even if I do:
        //return (count_type) 5;
        //return 5U;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    B b;

    A<B> a;

    a.add(b);
}
```

When I try to compile with `-Wconversion`, I get strange error message:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11  -Wconversion x.cc
x.cc: In instantiation of ‘A<T>::count_type A<T>::add(T) [with T = B; A<T>::count_type = short unsigned int]’:
x.cc:29:9:   required from here
x.cc:11:7: warning: conversion to ‘A<B>::count_type {aka short unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   sum += x.value();
       ^
```

Why this happens? There is no `int` anywhere?

I will be grateful if someone edit my question.

Note: `clang` does not give such warning.

Comment: _"There is no `int` anywhere"_ What did you think `5` would be?

Comment: There is no error message here at all, let alone a "strange" one. Only a warning.

Comment: count_type is cast-ed to count_type.

Comment: `5` is still an `int`.

Comment: see my update for 5U. 5U is not int for sure.

Comment: @Nick: `5u` is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The warning does not trigger for values that are known at compile time to be within `count_type`'s range before being converted to `count_type`. The fact that `5` is an `int` is correct but completely unrelated to the warning.

Comment: @hvd: When did I say it was related to the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum += x.value();` means (roughly) `sum = sum + x.value();` The RHS here, `sum + x.value()`, adds two `unsigned short` values and produces an `int`. Assigning that `int` back to an `unsigned short` can alter its value.

The warning is, in my opinion, not particularly useful and I suggest turning it off, but if you want to keep it enabled for some reason, write a cast there:

```
sum = (count_type) (sum + x.value());
```

or

```
sum = static_cast<count_type>(sum + x.value());
```

Comment: this is it!!! but why this not happen when type is not template-dependent?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The OP tried `sum += (count_type) x.value();`. That won't work, and it's not what I have in my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i casted  sum = sum + (count_type) x.value();

Comment: @Nick: you must not cast the operand but the result of the operation, eg `sum = (count_type)(sum + x.value())`.

Comment: @Nick I get the warning even if the type is not template-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

According to implicit promotions, any arithmetic expression (as `sum = sum + x.value()`) undergoes a pattern called *usual arithmetic conversions*, the relevant part from §5 of the standard:

> ...
>
> — Otherwise, **the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands**. 59 Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:

The integral promotions specifies:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t **whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`** if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

So operands are converted to `int`, then back to `unsigned short`. This because the conversion rank specifies that

> The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with a smaller size.

and

> The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.